# Can't Install Phantomjs on Windows with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs

So I'm trying to install phantom.js whilst at work. I can download the sourcecode for it and even have the .exe installed for it (so i can access the phantom shell). But its still not installed. When I try node ./install .js or npm install phantom.js I get this error.

```
connect ETIMEDOUT ip:port
This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
and is related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

or

```
Receiving...

Error making request.

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ipaddress:port

at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)

at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:883:20)

at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

My node version is v4.4.2 and I'm on Windows 7.

I've tried editing my .npmrc file (the one which contains my proxy information) so that it now has the line 
      phantomjs_cdnurl=https://cnpmjs.org/downloads

I've also tried adding bot the .exe file to my PATH and the sourcecode and still no luck. Finally, I've tried things the README suggests such as shell commands like "npm install phantomjs-prebuilt --phantomjs_cdnurl=https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads" but has the same errors as well. Is there something I'm missing/done wrong? help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: `tried adding the .exe file to my PATH` That is exactly what is needed. Describe how did you do it.

Comment: I found my PATH and then just copied the botht the sourcecode and the .exe into it. Then npm installed again.

Comment: Are you trying to install this on a VM or the actual machine? If you're on a VM, check your network connection. Are you online? Note that the error says it's timing out due to a network connectivity issue.

Comment: Its on an actual machine and I think that the network issue is because of a proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best thing to do which worked like a charm was to use phantomjs-that-works

```
  npm install -g phantomjs-that-works
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution here is to correctly add PhantomJS folder to PATH environment variable. For example if initially you have such PATH:

> C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\

then you add a semicolon and **the path to the folder** where PhantomJS resides, not to .exe itself. So it hypothetically PhantomJS is at `C:\Phantomjs\phantom.exe` you only add `;C:\Phantomjs\`:

> C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Phantomjs\

Then you press OK, then you **close the command prompt and open it again** so that it reads the updated PATH. After that you're free to use phantomjs by calling it by name `phantom` (if it's called `phantom.exe`) anywhere.

Comment: How's that? Do you not knoww how?

Comment: I don't have permission

Comment: Have you tried setting PATH only for your user?  maybe you have enough permissions for that? http://i.imgur.com/x9SVwfM.png

Comment: I can't do that either. However, the .exe i downloaded I placed in a PATH, it just comes back with "checksum did not match"

Comment: Probably a failed download. Redownload .exe, place it in your PATH and you'll be all set.